# Is there a difference between finding by primary key vs finding by unique column?

Tags: java, sql

If i have an entity with a primary key `id` and an unique column `name`. Is there any difference whether i do a SQL request `findById(long id)` or `findByName(String name)`. Can a search for the primary key be done in O(1) while the other one works in O(n)? Which data structures are used for saving them?

Comment: Technically, if you have indexes on both columns (and you must have it, since `name` is unique), they'll work the same. The only difference is that `id` is a primary key and can not be changed, whereas `name` is just a property which can be changed.

Comment: [This post over on DBA might be of interest](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/137945/indexes-integer-vs-string-performance-if-the-number-of-nodes-is-the-same). TL;DR is that numeric indexes are faster than string indexes, *how* much faster depends on the size of your strings.

Comment: Ok, so i guess theres no reason not to do a search based on the primary key which is an integer if its available.

Comment: @JonK, that post is related to PostgreSql. This might be different or quite not true for another DBMS.

Comment: In MS SQL primary key index is usually clustered. That could make performance a bit better.

Comment: @PavelSmirnov It certainly might, although for an RDBMS that's unlikely.

Comment: @PavelSmirnov .. how primary key can not be changed?

Comment: @Serg, either logically, or using a constraint provided by a DBMS. Either way, primary key is there to uniquely identify a record. If it's changed, you can not say it's the same record.

Answer (score 4):

The difference is speed :
Running SQL query against Integer will always be faster than running against a string.

Comment: Especially faster as the primary key is immutable as opposed to a unique column, and hence needs no _mutable_ index.

Answer (score 2):

From the perspective of order complexity of the operation, then the two are equivalent.

As others have pointed out, an integer lookup is generally faster than a string lookup.  Here are three reasons:

1. The index would typically be smaller because, integers are 4 bytes and strings are typically bigger.
2. Indexes on fixed length keys have some additional efficiencies in the tree structure (no need to "find the end of the string").
3. In many databases, strings incur additional overhead to handle collations.

That said, another factor is that the primary key is often clustered in many databases.  This eliminates the final lookup of the row in data pages -- which might be a noticeable efficiency as well.  Note that not all databases support clustered indexes, so this is not true in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

If both columns were `INTEGER`, then the answer would be "no". A `PRIMARY KEY` is effectively a `UNIQUE` constraint on a column and little more. Additionally, as usually they both cause internal indexes to be created, again they behave basically the same way.

In your specific case, however, the `NAME` column is a string. Even though it has a `UNIQUE` constraint, by virtue of its data type you will incur in some performance loss.

As your question is probably dictated by "ease of use" to some extent (for your debugging purposes it's certainly easy to remember the "name" than it is to remember the "id") the questions you need to ask yourself are:

- Will the `NAME` column always be unique or could it be change to something not unique? Should it actually be unique in the first place (maybe they set it up wrong)?
- How many rows do you expect in your table? This is important to know as while a small table won't really show any performance issue, a high cardinality may start to show some.
- How many transactions/second do you expect? If it's an internal application or a small amateurial project, you can live with the `NAME` column being queried whereas if you need extreme scalability you should stay away from it.